# download git repo using php

Tags: php, curl, github, download

I want to download a repository file from github after that the user doing an action. The code will not work as expected. A `.zip` file is created when the code run but the resulting zip file is blank. How I can fix this?

```
$url = "https://github.com/$u/$repo/archive/master.zip";
$ch = curl_init();
    $f = fopen(__DIR__.'/master.zip', 'w+');
    $opt = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_FILE => $f,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    ];
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opt);
    $file = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true` from your code or put it before `CURLOPT_FILE`.

This is [known interaction](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082) as `CURLOPT_FILE` depends on `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` being set.

Comment: I've tried, but it will continue generating a blank zip file (0 byte dimension). Is this caused because the download isn't done by curl?

Comment: @user10479680 why would you think it isn't downloaded by curl? Is your repository private?

Comment: Because I've added the `curl_error()` function to my code and it will output this error message `error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version` .

Comment: Maybe it's related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935450/php-curl-https-ssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1). Try checking what your curl and openSSL version is and updating if necessary.